Are Subscriber-to-LMO parameters directly accesible by Subscribers?
Salesforce documentation explicitly states that both Subscriber and Developers can edit the value of a Subscriber to LMO feature parameter.
However the documentation does not specify if anyone in the Subscriber org can edit feature parameters, if an specific permission is needed or if any kind or protection can be set for those parameters. Could any Subscriber user access the Feature Parameter simply by guessing it's name?
The use case is to collect usage metrics and charge Clients based on that, so obviously a Customer always setting it's value to 0 would give problems.
